# HTML5 + CSS3 100% height with margin

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML layout:

```html
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
    </header>

    <section class="site-section">
    </section>

    <footer class="site-footer">
    </footer>
</body>
```

I want to use 100% of the browser height for the header, section and footer. However, there's no problem to achieve that:

```
html, body { height:100%; }

.site-header  { height:10%; }
.site-section { height:80%; }
.site-footer  { height:10%; }
```

My problem is, that this won't work if I want to use a margin for each child of `body`:

```
body > * { margin:1%; }
```

No matter if there's a margin or not - the site should always use 100% of the browser height.

**EDIT:**
It seems to more suitable for me to use a white border instead. However, same problem remains. Is it even possible to specify `border-width` in percent?

Comment: do you really want to use percentages for your headers and footers? If you use fixed positioning as one answer below, you can accomplish the 100% page height, but I can't image a UX where you would want your headers and footer to grow in height.

Comment: Remember that vertical margins and paddings in CSS are computed based on the elements width, not height, therefore you will not be able to subtract percentages from the height by virtue of the desired margin width, and hope that it all fits. However, you can try (1) using an additional inner div for all header, section and footer content, and specify padding for the parent element or (2) use border width and box-sizing. p/s: Try transparent borders ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know this will look ridiculous and ugly, and stupid. Actually, it is. but i couldn't find a better way to approach exactly what you want without recurring to ugly markup.

HTML:

```
<header class="site-header">
</header>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<section class="site-section">
</section>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<footer class="site-footer">
</footer>

<div class="spacer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {height:100%;margin:0;} 
body > * { overflow:hidden;}
.spacer {height:1%;}
.site-header {height:8%;background-color:yellow; }
.site-section {height:78%;background-color:#ffcccc; color:#aaa;}
.site-footer {height:8%;background-color:#ccccff;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CZSFQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the margin from the height of the elements:

```
.site-header  { height:8%; }
.site-section { height:80%; }
.site-footer  { height:8%; }
```

Comment: You've forgotten to take margin collapsing into account.

Comment: That doesn't work - still fills more than 100% of the browser height.

Answer (score 0):

margin sums up to height. so basically you are doing:

.site-header { height:10%; margin:1%;} --> this translates to {height:12%}

To solve your problem, you can count the margin into the elements:

.site-header { height : 8% }

OR use the as wrappers without margin (which allows for px margins) and not styling the header, section and footer at all (which if im not wrong, will help to keep style consistent on older browsers also, specially if using selectors like > ).

```
body > * > div {margin: 1%}
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
        <div class="inner_header">
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="site-section">
        <div class="inner_section">
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="site-footer">
        <div class="inner_footer">
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: adding margins to the children will collapse out of the parents, padding would be one way out

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 `FLEX` property for this:

```
body {
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: vertical;
    width:100%;
}
body header,body section, body footer{
    display:block;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
    background:red;
    height:10%;
}
section{
    background:green;
    -webkit-box-flex: 3;
     -moz-box-flex: 3;
}
footer{
    background:yellow;
    height:10%;
}
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/14/

**UPDATED:**

### http://jsfiddle.net/XMg2h/15/

it's works till IE8 & above.

Comment: I'm not very fond of the alternative box models, and this wont work for IE (not very fond of IE either, but clients is clients).

Comment: @refhat; check these links http://www.css3.info/introducing-the-flexible-box-layout-module/,  http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-flexbox-20111129/

Answer (score 0):

mmmm Did you try with something like this?

```
cssSelector{width:200px; border:20px; box-sizing:border-box}
```

The key is the **box-sizing**, if we don´t use it the final width is equals to 220px, but when I use **box-sizing** the final width is equals to 200px, so, you can to try and see what happens.

:)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished using fixed positioning AND fixed heights for your header, footer, and margin.

```
<body>
    <header class="site-header"></header>
    <section class="site-section"></section>
    <footer class="site-footer"></footer>
</body>

html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body > * {
    position:fixed;
    margin:5px 0;
    width:100%
}
.site-header {
    top:0px;
    height:80px;
    background:red;
}
.site-section {
    top:85px;
    bottom:85px;
    background:green;
}
.site-footer {
    bottom:0px;
    height:80px;
    background:blue;
}
```

### And here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/RJrdr/2/)