# Set height to 20% for a div whose parent has min-height of 100%

Tags: html, css

I can't set a `height` (in %) to a `div` (`class="item"`) whose parent (`class="site-section"`) has a `min-height: 100%`.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>

<header class="site-header"></header>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<section class="site-section">
    <div class="column">
        <div>I would like to be able to set an later 
             change the height of this green item.
        <div class="item">ITEM</div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>

<footer class="site-footer"></footer>

<div class="spacer"></div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin 0;
    color:blue;
 } 
.spacer {
    height:1%;
 }
.site-header {
    height:8%;
    background-color:yellow;
 }
.site-section {
    min-height:78%;
    background-color:#ffcccc; 
    color:#aaa;
 }
.site-footer {
    height:8%;
    background-color:yellow;
 }
.column {
    width: 50%;
 }
.item {
    height: 40%; 
    background-color: #33cc33;}
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m4i4/CZSFQ/40/).

Everything was working fine until I added `DOCTYPE` to my HTML. There was no need to set `height` (in %) for `html`, `body` and `.site-section`, so `.item` was having his `height: 20%`. Now, because of `DOCTYPE` I need to set `height` for `html`, `body`, and `.site-section`. The consequence is that `.item` does not react to `height: 20%` anymore.

Any idea how to solve this?

P.S. I've based my demo on Bart's demo in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358495/html5-css3-100-height-with-margin).

Comment: Heights in percent only work if the parent element has an explicit height set. (Otherwise that might result in cat-chasing-its-own-tail situations – what if the height of the parent depends on the height of the child element(s), but those in return on the height of the parent? That’s an unsolvable equation, and therefor is not possible.)

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346867/css-cant-seem-to-set-height-to-100-of-parent-container

Comment: That’s explicitly [described in the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property) btw., _“height: `<percentage>`: […] If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.”_

Comment: It's not the issue, but the `div` prior to the div in question does not have a closing tag.

Comment: That missing </div> did not change anything. Still, I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe is correct in that you can't really get a height percent unless the parent itself has a height (ex. height: 35px). I would recommend setting the height of the div, then your inside divs can be set to percentages.

But I played a tiny bit with your fiddle and didn't know if adding `position: absolute` to the your class item CSS is sort of what you're looking for? So your CSS would look something like this:

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40%; 
    background-color: #33cc33;
}
```

Here is [the demo modified](http://jsfiddle.net/abrielshipley/CZSFQ/42/) to show the example.

**NOTE**: Even though the height is flexible, if you set the height to 100% it will go above the rest of the divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
.item{
        position:absolute;
        height:40%;
        background:#33cc33;
    }
.items {
        position:relative;
        height:100%;
        background:inherit;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="item">
      <div class='items'>
                    ITEM Try
      </div>
</div>
```

Try :)

Comment: Interesting solution. I only needed to add width: 50% to .item1 (I have renamed .item to .item1).

Besides, I've realised that what I'm trying to do is much more complex than I first thought. Namely, below .item1 I need another .item (.item2) of the same height. Actually I need to be able to add a flexible number of items below .item1 and of different heights also.

What I find strange is that if I set top: 40% to an .item2, it does not go below .item1.

Comment: ... and here is the DEMO

Comment: GOSH, I'm not used to Stack overflow! This 3 comments were not meant to this answer. So please ignore them.